# Django ImageField in RestFramework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm new at Django.
my project is in DjangoRestFramework

This project has a user:

**models.py:**

```
class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=False, default='phone')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
    natNum = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True)
    degImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images/degrees/', null=False, blank=False,default='Images/degrees/None/no-img.jpg')
    natImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images/nationalCards/', null=False, blank=False,default='Images/nationalCards/None/no-img.jpg')
    sex = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=1)
    province = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=40)
    job = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True)
    last_seen = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    points = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)
    scorers = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)
```

and in views.py I made a function for registeration but for degImage and natImage there is a problem.

**views.py**

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@parser_classes((MultiPartParser, JSONParser))
def register(request):
    user_data = request.data
    if user_data:
        serializer = UserSerializers(data=user_data)

        if serializer.is_valid():

            phone_number = serializer.validated_data["phone"]

            try:
                found_user = Users.objects.get(phone=phone_number)
            except Users.DoesNotExist:
                found_user = None

            if found_user:
                return Response({
                    "code": 211,
                    "status": "successfull",
                    "message": "user already exists, try to login"
                })
            else:
                destination = serializer.validated_data['phone']
                message = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
                url = "https://panel.asanak.ir/webservice/v1rest/sendsms/?Username=***&Password=***&Source=***&Destination={}&message={}"
                url = url.format(destination, message)
                r = requests.get(url)
                r.json()
                registerInfo = {
                    'name': serializer.validated_data['name'],
                    'lastName': serializer.validated_data['lastName'],
                    'phone': serializer.validated_data['phone'],
                    'natNum': serializer.validated_data['natNum'],
                    'password': serializer.validated_data['password'],
                    'degImage': serializer.validated_data['degImage'],
                    'natImage': serializer.validated_data['natImage'],
                    'sex': "",
                    'province': "",
                    'city': "",
                    'job': "",
                    'code': message
                }

                serializer.save(registerInfo)

                return Response({
                    "code": 200,
                    "status": "successfull",
                    "message": "code was sent try to validate code"
                })
            return Response({
                "status": "successfull",
                "error": "user created :)"
            })

        else:
            return Response({
                "status": "error",
                "error": "Bad request"
            })
    else:
        return Response({
            "status": "error",
            "error": "Empty request"
        })
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializers(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    lastName = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    phone = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    natNum = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    degImage = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    natImage = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    code = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    def save(self, validated_data):
        user = Users(
            name=validated_data['name'],
            lastName=validated_data['lastName'],
            phone=validated_data['phone'],
            natNum=validated_data['natNum'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
            degImage=validated_data['degImage'],
            natImage=validated_data['natImage'],
            code=validated_data['code']
        )
        user.save()
        return user
```

In Postman when i choose a file it's OK and works fine

But in developing android and iOS they can't post a image in json with other fields

and i want to know is there any problem in my coding that makes this problems or any thing which we can do to solve this

if there is any thing in swift to do this please tell me

i run my project on a server and you can check it to with the ip below:

http://176.31.82.35:3030/moshaver/register

Comment: files cannot be posted in Json data. You need to send images using form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we cannot send a filetype with header "Content-Type: application/json". 
Please make sure your request header should be set to **"Content-Type: multipart/form-data"**.
As you are using parsers `MultiPartParser, JSONParser` it will parse the file data as well as json data.